# osascript changes case in OSX10.12.1

Tags: terminal, applescript, macos

osascript is behaving weird after upgrading to 10.12.1. Prior to this version, the command works as below:

In 10.12, the output is in whatever case the input is:

```
deppfx : ~ $ osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"Hello\""
deppfx : ~ $ Hello
```

In 10.12.1, the output is forced to uppercase:

```
deppfx : ~ $ osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"Hello\""
deppfx : ~ $ HELLO
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Caps-lock is probably on. This inputs the text as if you typed it yourself, so it's affected by holding shift down, or having caps-lock on.

Comment: A direct caps-lock-on answer? No, it's not caps-lock. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't do that for me, except for when caps-lock is on, or I'm holding shift down.